# Draw within iOS Today Extension without scrolling the whole NC

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

Is it possible to draw with my fingers within the content of an iOS 8 widget without scrolling the whole Notification Center view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563472/dragging-gestures-in-ios-8-today-extensions

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended by Apple.
See
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1

There is a NOTE:
Avoid putting a scroll view inside a widget. It’s difficult for users to scroll within a widget without inadvertently scrolling the Today view.